# PageControl in Xcode UITest

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I have an app where a Page Control is used to indicate multiple of screens. When the user taps the page control (for example: to the right the of the current selected page), the scroll view scrolls to the following screen. It works fine.

I wanted to write a UI Test for this scenario. I found out that I cannot tap a specific page control "dot" to trigger that action. What I can check is that the Page Control exists and the current selected page.

Another issue is that even if I am able to do so, how can I check that the scroll view has scrolled already? I can only access the frame of the scroll view, not its bounds.

I have just started using Xcode UITest and it's letting me down. I thought it would be powerful by now (it was introduced by Xcode 7 and it was available before as UI Automation), but it seems it's not yet.

I will revert back to Unit Testing + manual functional testing. If anyone has other thoughts, please share it.

Comment: I added the `ios` tag since it looks like you are using UIPageControl, and also because it allows stackoverflow to set the code highlighting in answers.

Answer (score 7):

Don't give up so soon, Xcode UITest can be frustrating at times but once you figured out what tricks to use, they are quite powerful:

You test your UIPageControl like this:

```
func testPageIndicator() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()

    let scrollView = app.scrollViews.element(boundBy: 0)
    let pageIndicator = app.pageIndicators.element(boundBy: 0)

    // test that page indicator is updated when user scrolls to page 2
    scrollView.swipeLeft()
    XCTAssertEqual(pageIndicator.value as? String, "page 2 of 3")

    // test that scrollview scrolls to page 3 when user taps right of the current page in page indicator
    pageIndicator.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.9, dy: 0.2)).tap()
    XCTAssert(app.otherElements["page_3"].waitForExistence(timeout: 2))
    XCTAssertFalse(app.otherElements["page_2"].exists)
    XCTAssertEqual(pageIndicator.value as? String, "page 3 of 3")
}
```

You can tell the test where to tap on a UIElement by using the `coordinate` method. You hand a CGVector object to that method that describes where to tap.

For example a `CGVector(dx: 0.9, dy: 0.2)` tells the test to tap the element at the point that lies at 90% of its width and 20% of its height.

You can use this to tap left of right of the current page in the `UIPageIndicator`(see above code example)

To test if you are on the correct page in the UIScrollView you can set each pages `accessibilityIdentifier` to a unique string and then assert that the UIElement with that identifier exists after you tapped the page control.

In my case the pages are 3 UIViews. I set their `accessibilityIdentifier` to "page_1", "page_2" and "page_3" and then assert that "page_3" exists and "page_2" doesn't.

Comment: That's really complicated. I could have written this code using a more simple unit test and the test code would be more robust, clear, and maintainable (the 0.9 and 0.2 in your code, in particular, almost got me a heart attack!) I don't know, but it looks to me that even after all these years, UI testing is lacking a lot.

Comment: I don't think it's complicated at all. Certainly UnitTests are always more reliable than UITests but there are certain things that UnitTests cannot do. Like testing how your app's UI behaves when a user is actually using it. I totally agree that UITests should be more reliable and that hacky stuff like the coordinate stuff should not be necessary, but I don't think it's too bad either. It certainly beats manual testing.

Comment: It's definitely better than manual testing. I am automating the full process now, so manual testing is used mainly for interaction design testing - a whole other scope. Regarding the case of unit tests not being able to test specific user interactions, well, I have been able to do it (at least up until now). I have written test that goes from one VC to the other and test for UI elements and states. I think when UI testing becomes easier, it will replace such tests, but until then I am better off sticking to unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a extension I have for getting the number of pages and current page. It uses regex to find two numbers in the string `value` and assumes the bigger one is the number of pages and the smaller one is current page.

What is nice about it is it works even if your device/simulator is not set in English.

```
extension XCUIElement {

    func currentPageAndNumberOfPages() -> (Int, Int)? {
        guard elementType == .pageIndicator, let pageIndicatorValue = value as? String else {
            return nil
        }
        // Extract two numbers. This should be language agnostic.
        // Examples: en:"3 of 5", ja:"全15ページ中10ページ目", es:"4 de 10", etc
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^\\D*(\\d+)\\D+(\\d+)\\D*$", options: [])
        let matches = regex.matches(in: pageIndicatorValue, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: pageIndicatorValue.count))
        if matches.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }
        let group1 = matches[0].range(at: 1)
        let group2 = matches[0].range(at: 2)
        let numberString1 = pageIndicatorValue[Range(group1, in: pageIndicatorValue)!]
        let numberString2 = pageIndicatorValue[Range(group2, in: pageIndicatorValue)!]
        let number1 = Int(numberString1) ?? 0
        let number2 = Int(numberString2) ?? 0
        let numberOfPages = max(number1, number2)
        var currentPage = min(number1, number2)
        // Make it 0 based index
        currentPage = currentPage > 0 ? (currentPage - 1) : currentPage
        return (currentPage, numberOfPages)
    }

    /// return current page index (0 based) of an UIPageControl referred by XCUIElement
    func currentPage() -> Int? {
        return currentPageAndNumberOfPages()?.0 ?? nil
    }

    /// return number of pages of an UIPageControl referred by XCUIElement
    func numberOfPages() -> Int? {
        return currentPageAndNumberOfPages()?.1 ?? nil
    }
}
```

And you can use it like:

```
let pageCount = app.pageIndicators.element(boundBy: 0).numberOfPages() ?? 0
for _ in 0 ..< pageCount {
    app.pageIndicators.element(boundBy: 0).swipeLeft()
}
```